# Converting List of Generic type classes to List of Objects

Tags: java, collections

Hi as my generic type method returns the List as follows

```
 List<Class<Department>> departmentsByAppId = commonDao.getDaoData(new Object[]{appStateObject.getAppId()}, new String[]{"appId"}, new String[]{"eq"}, Department.class);
```

So how can we convert this data to normal list like`List<Department>` without iterating.

Comment: what is return type of commonDao.getDaoData method.

Comment: Hi  @ChamlyIdunil Iduni  Thanks for your reply, And the Return type of that method is <T> List<T> getDaoData(--).

Comment: What's `--` in parentheses? It is important.

Comment: @ShashiDk if return type is List<T> why you use List<Class... as variable type. cant you use List<Department>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your generic type method is declared in a generic interface and that department got a DAO interface that extends that last one, you could do something like that :

**YourGenericDaoInterface.java :**

```
public interface YourGenericDaoInterface<E> {

    List<E> getDaoData(Object[] objArray, String[] appId, String[] eq, Class clazz);

}
```

**YourGenericDaoImplementation.java :**

```
@Override
List<E> getDaoData(Object[] objArray, String[] appId, String[] eq, Class clazz) {
    // do your stuff here
}
```

**YourDepartmentDaoInterface.java :**

```
public interface YourDepartmentDaoInterface extends YourGenericDaoInterface<Department> {

}
```

So basically it does the following :

- By making `YourDepartmentDaoInterface` inherits `YourGenericDaoInterface<Department>` you obtain the method getDaoData and tell that the return type is of type Department then when you'll use your method you will directly call :

`List<Department> dep = commonDao.getDaoData(new Object[] appStateObject.getAppId()}, new String[]{"appId"}, new String[]{"eq"}, Department.class);`

Comment: Thanks @Deh. It worked. I didn't know like it is this much simple.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate the list and add each object to another list after performing the appropriate casting:-

```
 List list = new ArrayList();
    for(int i=0;i<=departmentsByAppId.size();i++)
    {
    list.add((Department)departmentsByAppId.get(i));
    }
```

Comment: "convert this data to normal list likeList<Department> **without iterating**."